# How to place order by and group by in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named td_cell_allocation which has the following data:

```
td_cell_allocation

|-------------|-----------|------------------------------------|---------------|
| first_name  | last_name |  user_email      |  cell_image     | continent     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|----------------
| saswat      | roy       | sas@gmail.com    |   a.jpg         |  america      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| shuvra      | pan       |   s@gmail.com    |   b.jpg         |  europe       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


td_cell_click

|-------------|-----------------|------------------|
| click_id    | user_mail       |  date_of_click   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     1       | sas@gmail.com   | 2013-06-2        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     2       | s@gmail.com     | 2013-06-2        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     3       | s@gmail.com     | 2013-06-3        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     4       | sas@gmail.com   | 2013-06-4        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     5       | s@gmail.com     | 2013-06-5        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     6       | sas@gmail.com   | 2013-06-5        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     7       | sas@gmail.com   | 2013-06-5        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     8       | sas@gmail.com   | 2013-06-8        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     9       | s@gmail.com     | 2013-06-8        |
----------------------------------------------------
```

now I want to sort the users having most clicks on month of june grouped by continent

so I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count( click_id ) AS tot_click, td_cell_allocation.continent
                        FROM td_cell_allocation, td_cell_click
                        WHERE td_cell_allocation.user_email = td_cell_click.user_mail
                        AND date_of_click LIKE '%-06-%'
                        GROUP BY td_cell_allocation.continent
                        ORDER BY tot_click DESC
```

It is returning me this:

```
shuvra         pan         2     europe  
shuvra         pan         2     europe  
saswat         roy         3     america
```

then i changed my query to

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT first_name, count( click_id ) AS tot_click, td_cell_allocation.continent
FROM td_cell_allocation, td_cell_click
WHERE td_cell_allocation.user_email = td_cell_click.user_mail
ORDER BY tot_click, timestamp DESC
) AS inv
GROUP BY inv.continent
```

it returned

```
saswat  7   america
```

I want my result be like this:

```
    saswat         roy         5     america  
    shuvra         pan         4     europe
```

Comment: Although there is some room for improvement your first query works just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64429/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing weird results is that you are not naming all non-aggregated columns in your group by.  Mysql (only) has some non-standard rules around grouping.

The first step is add the other columns to the group by:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count( click_id ) AS tot_click, td_cell_allocation.continent
FROM td_cell_allocation, td_cell_click
WHERE td_cell_allocation.user_email = td_cell_click.user_mail
AND date_of_click LIKE '%-06-%'
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, td_cell_allocation.continent
ORDER BY tot_click DESC
```

The next refinement is to change your query to a proper join:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count( click_id ) AS tot_click, td_cell_allocation.continent
FROM td_cell_allocation
JOIN td_cell_click ON td_cell_allocation.user_email = td_cell_click.user_mail
WHERE date_of_click LIKE '%-06-%'
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, td_cell_allocation.continent
ORDER BY tot_click DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.first_name,t1.last_name,count(t2.date_of_click) as cnt ,t1.continent 
from Table1 t1
Inner join Table2 t2
ON t1.user_email=t2.user_mail AND date_of_click LIKE '%-06-%'
Group BY continent
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c05f/1)